# Spring MVC - How to map individual methods in a controller without anotation use

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, mapping

I am very new to Spring framework in general. How can I map individual methods in a controller, so that I can call any other method other than handleRequestInternal for example.
Also I do not want to use annotation (@RequestMapping).

Thank you
manu

Answer (score 0):

If you use an interface based Controller than use manual dispatching to your methods, otherwise you have to use annotations I believe.

Comment: I went through the Spring MVC tutorial online and got my answer there. The use of MultiActionController is what I was looking for anyways thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You want Spring MVC's [convention over configuration support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-coc).  Check out [ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping.html).